# F# Type Constraint Mismatch when using a constraint on a generic function

Tags: .net, f#, inline

In an f# project I have the following types:

```
type A = { Name: string }
type B = { Name: string; SurName: string }
type C = { Name: string; SurName: string; MaidenName: string }
```

and the following function using a constraint on the generic argument:

```
let inline filterByName<'a when 'a: (member Name: string)> (name: string) (collection: 'a seq) =
    collection |> Seq.where(fun i -> i.Name = name)
```

The problem is I get the following compile time error:

> Type constraint mismatch. The type
>
> 'a
>
> is not compatible with type
>
> C
>
> The type ''a' does not match the type 'C'

Removing `inline` from the function definition gives me the following compile time error:

> This code is not sufficiently generic. the type variable ^a when
> ^a:(member get_Name: ^a -> string) could not be generalized because it
> would escape its scope.

What I am trying to achieve is have a function that takes a generic type with a property of a specific name, "Name" in this case. What am I doing wrong or what am i missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is how you're invoking the constrained member - you can't use the `i.Name` syntax, but instead must use a more verbose syntax.  On the bright side, this enables the signature of the method itself to be inferred, so you don't have to duplicate everything:

```
let inline filterByName name collection =
    collection |> Seq.where(fun i -> (^a : (member Name : string) i) = name)
```

Note also that you need to use a statically resolved type variable (`^a`) instead of a normal generic type variable (`'a`).